# Where files are allocated in Parse Server?

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

I'm implementing an instance of Parse Server, I want know where the Parse Server Allocated the files ?

Answer (score 1):

According to [File Adapter](https://docs.parseplatform.org/parse-server/guide/#configuring-file-adapters), the default file storage is [GridFS](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/api/GridFSBucket.html) in mongodb.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the operating system and type of installation you used.

If installed on a linux/unix using the global install  `npm install -g parse-server mongodb-runner`  then your parse-server files will normally be under `usr/lib/node_modules/parse-server`. ( may differ from linux versions )

be careful when editing these files for hot hacks or modifications. If you later choose to upgrade parse-server they will be overwritten.

Your cloud file directly is normally created by you. So this could be `home/parse/cloud/main.js`. This can be in any location of your choice. To set a new location you will set that in the index file or json (depending on your startup process ).

`cloud: '/home/myApp/cloud/main.js', // Absolute path to your Cloud Code`

If you installed not using the global install, then obviously you would need to cd to where you cloned the project.

Windows would be similar. Clone (or download the zip) parse-server from the repo. Open a console window and “cd” to the folder where you have cloned/extracted the example server, eq:

```
cd "C:\parse-server"
```

Here is where the files will sit on the parse-server. Hopes this helps!

Comment: i think he meant to ask- "where are File-objects stored?"