# parse server, retrieve all files on server

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

can someone point out how I can identify or list all images on my parse server. I thought this was a drop in a localfolder called files, but it seems now, upload works just fine with the following:

```
  var fileUploadControl = $('#companyLogo')[0];
            if (fileUploadControl.files.length > 0) {
                var file = fileUploadControl.files[0];
                var name = 'companyLogo';
                var companyLogo = new Parse.File(name, file);
                companyLogo.save().then(function(response) {
                    $timeout(function () {
                        resolve(response);
                    }, 250);
                }, function(error) {
                    ngProgressLite.done();
                });
            }
```

Comment: https://github.com/parse-server-modules/parse-files-utils  may help you select/process parse "files"

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where generic parse files are saved to. I would suggest creating a 'company' object and have 'logo' as a column with the type of 'file' so it is better organized. I would just open up the database and see where the logos are being stored at.

Comment: I tried that but there is no physical location. I might have to save my own physically and save the url

Comment: refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41213387/where-files-are-allocated-in-parse-server/54165965#54165965